# spring security quick start

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to follow this to incorporate spring security in the framework

http://java.dzone.com/tips/pathway-acegi-spring-security-

i hope to make a basic form based authentication, so i think this would be a great pointer.

if i am using the spring security 3 libraries, would there be any different?

which file is the authentication-manager xml would suppose to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've done a migration from Acegi Security to Spring Security, and I should say that it went pretty smooth, without any significant issues. So I assume that this libraries (in fact Spring Security is a latter version of Acegi) have not too much differences.

You could include you `AuthenticationProvider` implementation or any configuration related to a security any context configuration file. However, it's generally preferable to keep in separate Spring XML config file, which name is passed as a parameter along with name of main config file when you are creating `ApplicationContext` instance.

Suppose you have class `MyAuthenticationProvider` :

```
 ...
 import org.springframework.security.providers.AuthenticationProvider;
 ...

 public final class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
       ...

    }
 }
```

This class is a regular Spring bean and therefore you can inject there any other bean you need, particularly DAO object which works with 'Users' table. Inside `authenticate` method you recieve partially initialized `Authentication` object. It's supposed to contain username and password. Here you could compare user credentials against database records.

Comment: i have done with AuthenticationProvider with the tutorial instructions and have put them on a separate xml namely applicationContext-security and have had it included from applicationContext.xml. now i would need to figure out how to get them to work with daoAuthenication manager, which reads user passwords from the database?

Answer (score 1):

also trying this one and succeed. this one is more complete with the included file 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Comment: I tried that one and it failed.  There were gradle build errors trying to build.  Also, I had to manually check out the SVN archive, the SVN plugin in eclipse didn't check out some of the files for some reason.  I wish that tutorial had more detail to it...